# mysql_query not returning data

Tags: php, mysql

The table `Users` contains data but still it shows `Records Not Found`

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "Assign1");
$records = mysql_query($conn, "select * from Users");

if(!$records)
{
    echo "No Records Found";
    exit();
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($records))
{
    echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['pwd'];
    echo "<br />";
}

mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Check for record count like this: if (mysql_num_rows($records) ==0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets resolve this issue first.**The error it was actually showing is no database selected** you have to select the database that needs the code

> mysql_select_db("Assign1",$conn);

Hope this code will perfectly sole your issue .Try it once .........

```
 <?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "pass");
mysql_select_db("Assign1",$conn);
$result = mysql_query("select * from users", $conn);
if(!$result)
{
    echo "No Records Found";
    exit();
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo $row[0]['name'];
  echo "<br />";
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 11):

You have the parameters to `mysql_query` reversed. It should be:

```
$records = mysql_query("select * from Users", $conn);
```

Your other issue is with the `if` statement. You're checking `if` on a query, not on a result set.

Also, I'm sure you probably know but `mysql` libraries are deprecated and are being removed. You should really learn to use `mysqli` functions as they will be far more useful to you in the future.

[Link to MySQLi documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) - It's really no harder than `mysql` libraries.

To re-implement in correct libraries:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "database");
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users");
$results = $query->fetch_assoc();

if($results) {
    foreach($results as $row) {
        echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['pwd'] . "<br/>";
    }
} else {
    echo "No results found.";
}

?>
```

Hopefully I didn't just do your whole assignment for you, but it'd probably be worth it to get one more person using mysqli properly.

Comment: @user2306964 - Have edited with enough information to get it working using the right libraries.

Comment: @user2306964 What is NOT working? Perhaps you should try echoing an error. For example, include `or die(mysql_error());` to the end of the connection and query statements like this: `mysql_query(...) or die( mysql_error());` At least then you know that the statement run.

Comment: @user2306964 Also it's best you change to mysqli like **Oshawott** has shown.

Comment: @user2306964 - Is this still not working for you? I just basically rewrote your program from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong usage of `mysql_query` function

use it like this:

```
 <?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "pass","Assign1");
$result = mysql_query("select * from Users", $conn);
if(!$records)
{
echo "No Records Found";
exit();
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['pwd'];
  echo "<br />";
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: WHAT is the RIGHT way then?

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```
 <?php

 $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "Assign1");
 mysql_select_db(' ----your-database-here---', $conn ) ;
 $records = mysql_query($conn, "select * from Users");

 if(mysql_num_rows($records) > 0 )
 {
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($records))
 {
echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['pwd'];
echo "<br />";
}   


 }else
{
echo "No Records Found";
exit();
}



mysql_close($conn);

?>
```